# Riak Cloud Storage gives me Forbidden access message after successful access many times before

Tags: amazon-s3, boto, riak, riak-cs

After many times of successful access to Riak CS storage using boto, it suddenly gave me this message:

```
S3ResponseError: S3ResponseError: 403 Forbidden
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Error><Code>InvalidAccessKeyId</Code><Message>The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.</Message><Resource></Resource><RequestId></RequestId></Error>
```

I'm not really sure what is the reason, but I think it has to do with access token expiry or something.

My question is: if the problem is the access token expiry, how do I change that in Raik CS configurations. And, if this is not the problem, what can it be?

**-- UPDATE --**

Riak logs: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/3028b1472b97c7dfcdfb

Riak CS logs: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/0c5c01a4ae215b34dadd

Comment: You'll need to check the logs for both Riak CS and Riak.  This problem could be caused by a connection error, disk error, or many other things.

Answer (score 1):

The log of Riak shows `emfile` errors, so you seemed to have encountered file handle limit. Please refer the doc to configure the limit [1].

[1] http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/ops/tuning/open-files-limit/

Comment: Thanks for your answer .. 2 questions here: 1- Is this limit is per user? because when I create another account things work with the new account until it saturates and give the above error .. 2- What is the open files limit that will allow hundreds of thousands of users to be able to work with their buckets. Or this limit is per user as I referred in my first question?

Comment: In the context of open file limit, I mean OS users, not CS users. If you still have `emfile` errors, you should set open file limit to the OS user who starts riak-cs OS process.